# Check proof that $\frac{4n^2-7}{2n^3-5}$ converges to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Check proof that $\frac{4n^2-7}{2n^3-5}$ converges to $0$.

WTS: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $\left| \frac{4n^2-7}{2n^3-5} - 0 \right| < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose $N = max(3, \frac{2}{\epsilon}) > 0$

Suppose $n > N$, then if $\frac{|4n^2-7|}{|2n^3-5|} = n^2\frac{\left|4-\frac{7}{n^2}\right|}{|2n^3-5|}$

Helper assumption: If $n > 3$, then $4 - \frac{7}{n^2} \leq 4$

$$n^2\frac{4-\frac{7}{n^2}}{2n^3-5} \leq \frac{2}{n} < \frac{2}{N} = \epsilon$$

Is this right?

Comment: Are you required to use epsilon-delta?

Comment: That was so quick. Yes. I'm iffy on the step for $\leq \frac{2}{n}$ otherwise i think this is right

Comment: In your "helper assumption", I think the numerator $3$ should be a $7$?

Comment: it was true for n = 4. Am i missing something?

Comment: If you can see "at once" that it converges to $0$ then always try to find a way to make profit from that. In comments and answers you see some of these ways. It will spare you a lot of time and the probability on errors is much smaller.

Comment: A proof of the crucial step $$n^2\frac{4-\frac{7}{n^2}}{2n^3-5} \leq \frac{2}{n}$$ is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Much less messy way which doesn't use $\epsilon/\delta$: note that the sequence is always positive for $n>1$, and it is bounded above by $\frac{4n^2}{2n^3-5}$ and hence by $\frac{4n^2}{n^3}$ whenever $n>1$.

Therefore the sequence is positive and bounded above by $\frac{4}{n}$, which converges to $0$; so the sequence converges to $0$.

---

It's a useful exercise to show that a positive sequence, bounded above by a sequence which converges to $0$, converges to $0$. You should try this with $\epsilon/\delta$ methods; that way, you can claim to have solved your problem using $\epsilon/\delta$ while still skipping out most of the fiddly bits.

Comment: My appreciation for the last suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**A "safe" way**:

By looking at the main terms in the numerator and denominator, the behavior is asymptotic to $2/n$. Then

$$\frac{4n^2-7}{2n^3-5}-\frac2n=\frac{4n^3-7n-4n^3+10}{(2n^3-5)n}=\frac{-7n+10}{(2n^3-5)n}=-\frac7{2n^3-5}+\frac{10}{(2n^3-5)n}.$$

Hence

$$\frac{4n^2-7}{2n^3-5}=\frac2n-\frac7{2n^3-5}+\frac{10}{(2n^3-5)n}$$
clearly converges to $0$.